# Is there a way to mirror a python function?

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am a student taking my first python class and we are using `Turtle` to draw an image. In an effort to save time I am trying to create a mirror function that can flip one functions results over the y-axis by a given number of pixels. For the sake of simplicity I created some functions to speed up my coding. Here is how my code works:

```
units, north, east, south, west = desiredPixelsPerUnit, 90, 0, 270, 180

def main():
    eye(30, 15)
    eye(40, 15)

def left():
    myTurtle.left(90)
def draw(count):
    distance = units * count
    myturtle.forward(distance)
def singleStep(xDirection, yDirection, stepCount):
    down()
    for step in range(stepCount):
        if yDirection == north:
            point(north)
            draw(1)
            if xDirection == east:
                point(east)
                draw(1)
         etc..
def eye(xPosition, yPosition):
    ....
    draw(3)
    left()
    draw(2)
    left()
    ....
    singleStep(east, north, 1)
    singleStep(west, north, 2)
    etc....
```

All of this gives me the following

Result of running `eye()` in main twice:

[image]

What I am trying to create is a function that is passed another function then will look at what is being executed. if it is `left()` or `right()` run the opposite. If it is point `(x, y)` add `180` `to` x. If it has a function call that inside the function then it checks that as well for lefts or rights. Something like this.

```
def mirror(function):
    for action in function:
        if action == left():
            execute right()
        ...
        elif action == singleStep():
            newFunction = singleStep()
            for action in newFunction:
                if:
                    statement above
                else:
                    statement below
       else:
           execute initial action
```

I am still very new to coding and programming. I have tried using arrays, associative arrays and lists, using `eval` and more. The time spent trying to figure it out has been far longer than writing a separate instruction list for the left and the right hahah but I really want to figure out how to do something like this.

Comment: You could try swapping over `left` and `right` on `myTurtle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could step back from calling `left()` and `right()` directly. Just create your own functions `your_left()` and `your_right()` and use them everytime. Then use a global variable called `mirror`. This variable will work as a flag for you. So you just set `mirror` to `True` when you want to mirror the output.

Your functions `your_right()` and `your_left()` will be looking something like this:

```
def your_right():
    left() if mirror else right()

def your_left():
    right() if mirror else left()
```

And then you are free to mirror all your outputs, if you want to. I hope i could help!

Comment: This was so simple that it made me feel like a dummy for not seeing this option before posting this question! This is certainly the easiest way to do this!

Comment: using this I was actually able to create a global variable for mirrorX and mirrorY which now allows me to mirror over either axis or over both. I'd say it more than answered my question!

Comment: Nice answer! I guess I was over-complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that using [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield-stmt):

```
import turtle

def function(): # Your function here, with the action calls replaced with yielding the un-called action, along with the argument
    for _ in range(4):
        yield turtle.forward, 100
        yield turtle.right, 90

def mirror(function):
    actions = {turtle.right: turtle.left,
               turtle.left: turtle.right,
               turtle.forward: turtle.backward,
               turtle.backward: turtle.forward}
    for action, argument in function():
        actions[action](argument)

mirror(function)
```

Breaking it down:

1. When defining the function that will be passed into the `mirror` function,
   do not call the turtle commands. Instead, use `yield` to yield the functions and arguments
   as tuples, so that the `mirror` function will be able to access which functions should be called.
2. In the `mirror` function, define a dictionary of turtle commands, `actions`, that would be used to mirror with.
3. Iterate through the yielded turtle actions from the function passed into the brackets of the `mirror` function, and unpack the tuples into `action, argument` pairs to be used to mirror.

Comment: I did not even know about this command! Thank you so much for this! I am about to try it out and do some research on yield!!

Comment: To be fair I am only in my second coding class and the last one was c# so I still have a LOOOOT to learn! Thanks again for helping out a noobie!

Comment: @armysBest Anytime!